# Sequential Script Loading using Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, here-api

I am trying to load Here Maps JS scripts using Promises. I have three scripts and the last two are dependent on the first one and can be loaded async once the first has loaded. The problem is after the first script loads it doesn't wait for the function in the **then()** :

```js
const libraries = {
    mapsjsCore: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js',
    mapsjsService: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js',
    mapjsEvents: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js'
};

const headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

export const loadMap = function () {

    // First script loads, returns immediately and
    // starts initializing the map without
    // waiting the last two scripts to load ???
    
    return getLibrary(libraries.mapsjsCore)
    .then(() => Promise.all([
    
            // Load the rest async
            getLibrary(libraries.mapsjsService),
            getLibrary(libraries.mapjsEvents)
        ])
    )
    .catch(error => new Error('Unable to load map files'))
}

function getLibrary(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let scriptHTML = document.createElement('script');

        scriptHTML.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptHTML.charset = 'utf-8';
        scriptHTML.async = true;
        scriptHTML.src = url;

        scriptHTML.onload = function () {
            resolve(url);
        }
        scriptHTML.onerror = function () {
            reject('error')
        }

        headTag.appendChild(scriptHTML);
    })
}
```

The loading sequence seems OK:

[image: loading sequence screenshot]

So how to make the the **loadMap()** to wait the **then()** and then return? Even if I wrap the **loadMap()** in a Promise and resolve after the **then()**, the result is the same? What am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? What is 'not waiting' for the `then` block? The scripts themselves? The scripts will run as soon as they are loaded, though they will be loaded in order thanks to the promise chain.

Comment: `loadMap` is not going to wait, that's the standard behavior for a Promise. Why do you want to wait? Do you need to execute something after the `Promise.all` completes?

Comment: The chain should be the following: load(1.js).then(load(2.js, 3.js).then(initMap())). What I have now is the following: load(1.js).then(initMap()).then(load(2.js,3.js)). So the problem is that after the first script loads, the loadMap() returns and starts initializing the map without waiting the last two scripts to load.

Comment: There's no `initMap()` in your sample script.

Comment: As @Evert mentioned, there is no `initMap()`.  You code shown above looks good and it runs as I would expect.  Show how you use `initMap()` in this context.

Comment: @psiphi75  I am exporting loadMap() and chaining it to the initMap() like so: loadMap().then(initMap()).

Comment: @avf, It's important you show all the code.  But I think I have an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks @psiphi75. Your answer solved it. Damn, it was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments above, it seems like you tried:

```
loadMap().then(initMap());
```

But the problem here is that `initMap()` will execute immediately.  You should use the following syntax:

```
loadMap().then(initMap);
```

The `initMap` function will be executed only once the maps have all been loaded.

Below is a complete working example.

```js
const libraries = {
    mapsjsCore: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js',
    mapsjsService: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js',
    mapjsEvents: 'http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js'
};

const headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

const loadMap = function () {

    // First script loads, returns immediately and
    // starts initializing the map without
    // waiting the last two scripts to load ???
    
    return getLibrary(libraries.mapsjsCore)
    .then(() => Promise.all([
    
            // Load the rest async
            getLibrary(libraries.mapsjsService),
            getLibrary(libraries.mapjsEvents)
        ])
    )
    .catch(error => new Error('Unable to load map files'))
}

function getLibrary(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let scriptHTML = document.createElement('script');

        scriptHTML.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptHTML.charset = 'utf-8';
        scriptHTML.async = true;
        scriptHTML.src = url;

        scriptHTML.onload = function () {
            console.log(`Loaded: ${url}`);
            resolve(url);
        }
        scriptHTML.onerror = function () {
            reject('error')
        }

        headTag.appendChild(scriptHTML);
    })
}

function initMap() {
  console.log(`initMap`);
}

loadMap().then(initMap);
// This prints
//   Loaded: http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js
//   Loaded: http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js
//   Loaded: http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js
//   initMap
```